# Lower bound for the number of partial orders

Tags: order-theory

I was wondering if there is a lower bound or a recursive relation for $P_n$ , the number of partial orders or posets on a set of $n$ elements.

I have noticed that $P_n>P_{n-1}, \forall n\geq 2$.
It seems that this bound is somewhat insignificant and trivial, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of results from the 1960s and 1970s about such asymptotics or bounds on the numbers of posets / particular kinds of posets / topologies on $n$ points.

For example, Kleitman and Rothschild (1970), building on an earlier result by Chatterji (1966), show that
$$
P_n \ge 2^{n^2/4}.
$$

This is for "labeled" posets (the $n$ points are labeled, so for example with $n=2$ the posets $1<2$ and $2<1$ are distinct), but since the numbers grow much faster than $n!$, for large $n$ it does not matter much whether you allow permutations of the $n$ points or not (i.e. consider labeled or unlabeled posets).

The exact numbers of (labeled) posets are known up to $n=18$ due to Brinkmann and McKay (2002), and are listed in OEIS [A001035](https://oeis.org/A001035). No simple recursive relation is known that would allow easy calculation of $P_n$ for large $n$; the exact results are based on a lot of computation by cases (see the Brinkmann & McKay paper for details).

- *Brinkmann, Gunnar; McKay, Brendan D.*, [**Posets on up to 16 points**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1016543307592), Order 19, No. 2, 147-179 (2002). [ZBL1006.06003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1006.06003).
- *Kleitman, D.; Rothschild, B.*, [**The number of finite topologies**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1970-0253944-9) Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 25:276-282 (1970)