# On counting transitive relations

Tags: combinatorics

Let $t_n$ denote the number of transitive relations on $n$ elements.

What reasonable $\alpha=\alpha(n)$  would you choose for $n\geq 2$ so that $$t_{n+1}\geq \alpha \times t_n$$
Or $$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}\geq \alpha$$

Obviously, the larger the value of $\alpha$, the better.

So far, I have come up with the fact that $\alpha\geq 2$. Can we make it better?

Comment: There's now a bounty for a "canonical answer", but I find it unclear what counts as such. Literally the question is asking (1) whether $\alpha$ can be made bigger than two (already answered), and (2) "what reasonable" $\alpha$ can be chosen. What is reasonable? Bigger than six? Bigger than bigger? As big as possible?

Comment: The bigger, the better.

Comment: So the bounty is for biggest constant $\alpha$ that applies to all $n \ge 2$? In particular, you are not looking for anything bigger than $171/13$ because anything bigger will not be true for $n=2$? And you are not looking for nonconstant lower bounds?

Comment: Bounds in terms of n will do.

Comment: So the question changed again? From the original question I read "what reasonable $\alpha \in \mathbb R$", that is, a constant lower bound. At some point you commented "bigger than six" but deleted it. What is the final version of the question?

Comment: Oh, it seems to be a chameleon question. If it is fully answered, the question changes to something different.

Comment: I have posted the final version.

Comment: Well, I'm done with this game. I answered the question fully, three times in its previous versions. First you asked for better than two (done), then best possible constant (done), then a bound in terms of $n$ (done).

Comment: Alright. Your bounty should reach you within an hour or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you want a lower bound $\alpha$ that holds *for all $n$ large enough* (that is, for all $n$ bigger than some value $n_0$). If you want it *for all $n \ge 2$* then $\alpha=171/13 \approx 13.15$ is the best you can hope because $t_3/t_2 = 171/13$.

But we should be able to do much better. Looking at [A006905](https://oeis.org/A006905), which begins $1, 2, 13, 171, 3994, 154303, \ldots$, it appears that the growth is *faster* than exponential (the ratios keep increasing). So the first guess is that any positive $\alpha$ would be eventually exceeded.

Check Götz Pfeiffer's paper (2004), Table 1 for a nice overview of different kinds of binary relations. Observe that *partial orders* are the same as *acyclic reflexive transitive relations*. Already this subset is known to grow faster than exponentially, namely $P_n \ge 2^{n^2/4}$ (see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249047/lower-bound-for-the-number-of-partial-orders)).

Now of course a lower bound on $t_n$, however fast-growing, does not directly give you a lower bound on $t_{n+1}/t_n$. (What if eventually we find that every odd entry $t_{2k+1}$ equals the previous even entry $t_{2k}$, with ratio $1$, and the growth happens only when going from $2k+1$ to $2k+2$?)

### Proof that we can take $\alpha=6$

It is easy to show at least $\alpha=6$. Take any transitive relation on $n \ge 1$ elements $1,2,\ldots,n$. You can extend it to three different transitive relations on $n+1$ elements:

1. $n+1$ has no relations with $1,\ldots,n$ in either direction; or
2. for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, you add $(i,n+1)$ to the relation; or
3. for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, you add $(n+1,i)$ to the relation.

In each case you can also choose to add $(n+1,n+1)$ or not, so you get $6$ relations. All these are transitive relations and different (and the extensions that you get from different $n$-element relations are also different). So $t_{n+1} \ge 6t_n$ for all $n \ge 1$.

### Proof that for all $n \ge 2$, we have $t_{n+1}/t_n \ge 2n$ and $t_{n+1}/t_n \ge 171/13$

For $2 \le n \le 6$ the claim is true by direct inspection of the ratios $t_{n+1}/t_n$ in [A006905: Number of transitive relations on n labeled nodes](https://oeis.org/A006905).

Let $n \ge 7$. For every transitive relation $T$ on $[n] := \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ do as follows. Let $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ be a listing of the elements $[n]$ in a linear order compatible with $T$. Then for every $k=1,\ldots,n$, let $$T_k = T \cup \{(x_j,n+1) \;:\; j=1,\ldots,k\},$$ that is, place a new element $n+1$ above the first $k$ elements of $T$ (in terms of the linear order).

Now $T_k$ is a transitive relation on $[n+1]$. In particular, if you take $u,v \in [n]$ such that $u \ne v$ and $(u,v),(v,n+1) \in T_k$, then by construction also $(u,n+1) \in T_k$, because the relation $(u,v)$ implies that $u$ comes before $v$ in the linear order.

The relations $T_k$ and $(T')_{k'}$ are different whenever $T\ne T'$ or $k \ne k'$ or both, so from $t_n$ transitive relations on $[n]$ we get $n t_n \ge 7t_n$ transitive relations on $[n+1]$.

From each $T_k$ make another transitive relation by adding the loop $(n+1,n+1)$. This doubles the number so we have
$$t_{n+1}/t_n \ge 2n \ge 14 > 171/13.$$

Note that $t_3/t_2 = 171/13$ so the constant lower bound $171/13$ is tight. There is no greater constant lower bound that applies to all $n \ge 2$. (Nonconstant lower bounds, or lower bounds that start to apply only later, are a different fish to fry.)

### Bibliography

- *Pfeiffer, Götz*, [**Counting transitive relations**](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL7/Pfeiffer/pfeiffer6.html), J. Integer Seq. 7, No. 3, Art. 04.3.2, 11 p. (2004). [ZBL1071.06003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1071.06003).

Comment: I want $t_{n+1}$ in terms of $t_n$. Regarding the fact that there is a lower bound for $P_n$ and that $t_n$ is expressible in terms of $P_n$, I am only looking for increasing $\alpha$, for all $n\geq2$.

Comment: Originally you asked if $\alpha=2$ can be improved. A bigger constant solves that. If you now ask for *increasing* $\alpha$ it seems to be a new question.

Comment: Yes. What other value of $\alpha$ do you suggest?

Comment: My answer gives $6$ as a lower bound. Do you now want a bigger value?

Comment: Yes. The bigger, the better. And how did you get $6$?

Comment: Isn't it in the answer?

Comment: It may be there, but it is not visible to me (with my naked eyes).

Comment: I have now highlighted that part. I think I have now given you the fishing rod. If you want more fish, you can continue from there.

Comment: Dear Firdous, try it yourself with your brand new fishing rod. If you succeed in proving a larger $\alpha$, you can post it as an answer of your own.

Comment: What do you mean by "a linear order compatible with T"?