# Is there a better lower bound on $|P_n|$, the number of posets on a set

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Regarding the set of partial orders $P_n$ on an $n$-set, it is well-known that $$|P_n|\geq {2^\frac{n^2}{4}}$$. This lower bound was given long back and I am not fully aware what improvements, if any, was made to this lower bound.

Is there a known improvement of this lower bound? I am asking this because it seems not a very good lower bound for $|P_n|$.

Comment: Some discussion here also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249047/lower-bound-for-the-number-of-partial-orders

Comment: It seems the question was closed as a duplicate. I'd say the questions are related but different. This time the question is specifically about a lower bound better than $2^{n^2/4}$, which was *not* the earlier question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Kleitman and Rothschild (1975) have a better lower bound, and they even show that it is asymptotically very tight.

Let $P_n$ be the number of posets on $n$ labeled elements; and let
$$
Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \binom{n}{i} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i} \binom{n-i}{j} (2^i-1)^j (2^j-1)^{n-i-j}.
$$
K&R prove that
$$
Y_n < P_n \le Y_n (1+O(1/n)).
$$
They also prove a simpler asymptotic expression:
$$
\log_2 P_n = A_n + O(\log_2 n).
$$
where
$$
A_n = n^2/4 + 3n/2.
$$
This is not that much different from the "trivial" lower bound $T_n = n^2/4$.

Let us compare to the known exact values ([A001035](https://oeis.org/A001035)).

$$
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
 n &   T_n    &  A_n     & \log_2(Y_n) & \log_2(P_n) \\
\hline
 1 &   0.2500 &   1.7500 &  -\infty &   0.0000 \\ 
 2 &   1.0000 &   4.0000 &   1.0000 &   1.5850 \\ 
 3 &   2.2500 &   6.7500 &   4.1699 &   4.2479 \\ 
 4 &   4.0000 &  10.0000 &   7.4094 &   7.7748 \\ 
 5 &   6.2500 &  13.7500 &  11.1737 &  12.0468 \\ 
 6 &   9.0000 &  18.0000 &  15.4635 &  16.9884 \\ 
 7 &  12.2500 &  22.7500 &  20.2760 &  22.5474 \\ 
 8 &  16.0000 &  28.0000 &  25.5962 &  28.6855 \\ 
 9 &  20.2500 &  33.7500 &  31.4190 &  35.3734 \\ 
10 &  25.0000 &  40.0000 &  37.7391 &  42.5880 \\ 
11 &  30.2500 &  46.7500 &  44.5551 &  50.3105 \\ 
12 &  36.0000 &  54.0000 &  51.8656 &  58.5254 \\ 
13 &  42.2500 &  61.7500 &  59.6705 &  67.2197 \\ 
14 &  49.0000 &  70.0000 &  67.9698 &  76.3823 \\ 
15 &  56.2500 &  78.7500 &  76.7638 &  86.0036 \\ 
16 &  64.0000 &  88.0000 &  86.0528 &  96.0754 \\ 
17 &  72.2500 &  97.7500 &  95.8374 & 106.5904 \\ 
18 &  81.0000 & 108.0000 & 106.1177 & 117.5421 \\ 
\end{array}
$$

So $Y_n$ are clearly better lower bounds than $2^{T_n}$. Note that $A_n$ are only asymptotically correct; for small $n$ they are not in fact lower bounds.

Looking at $Y_n$ and $P_n$ for small $n$, although the differences $\log_2(P_n)-\log_2(Y_n)$ are increasing, the increase is slowing down so it is still plausible that it would eventually reverse and the differences would tend to zero (as claimed).

- *Kleitman, D. J.; Rothschild, B. L.*, [**Asymptotic enumeration of partial orders on a finite set**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1997200), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 205, 205-220 (1975). [ZBL0302.05007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.05007).